# Requirement on being countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is this statement true?

If $A$ is in a 1-1 correspondence (bijection) with a countable set (not necessarily the set of positive integers) then $A$ is countable.

Thanks.

Comment: Please take another look at the tags before using them. This is the second question about countability you have tagged with general-topology.

Comment: Sorry. What tag should i use then? Is it first countable?

Comment: Don't worry too much about the tags. Just do your best. If you don't get them just right, someone else will fix them, and you can take note of what they did and try to use that to do better next time. Welcome to math stackexchange!

Comment: @MJD Thanks. What you guys do here in SE really is great help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is true, by definition of countable set.

If $f:A\to B$ is bijection where $B$ is countable and $g:B\to \mathbb{N}$ is also a bijection (it exist since $B$ is countable), then is also $g\circ f :A\to \mathbb{N}$ a bijection, so $A$ is countable.

Comment: $g$ could be an injection. [Assuming we are taking countable in its usual sense, rather than as countably infinite.]